# Find minimum value of $P=\sum \frac{a}{a^2+b^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $a,b,c$ be non-negative numbers and $a+b+c=3$, then find minima value of function $$P=\frac{a}{a^2+b^3}+\frac{b}{b^2+c^3}+\frac{c}{c^2+a^3}$$

---

Here is my idea.

By WA i see that if the equality occurs  $a=b=c=1$, we will get $\text {Min}_P=1.5$. Indeed i will prove $P\ge 1.5$ by BW and C-S

We have: 
$$\text{L.H.S}=3\sum \frac{a^2}{a^3\sum a+3ab^3}\ge \frac{3\left(\sum a\right)^2}{\left(a+b+c\right)\left(\sum a^3\right)+3\sum ab^3}$$

Or $$2\left(\sum a\right)^4\ge 9\left(\sum a\right)\left(\sum a^3\right)+27\left(\sum ab^3\right)$$

I tried BW here but failed.The last inequality is wrong. Help me.

Comment: Let $a,b \to 0$ and $c \to 3$ then you have $P \to 1/3$ so indeed you can get much smaller than your proposed $P_{min} = 1.5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Andreas's hint it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+b^3}\geq\frac{1}{3}.$$
Now, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+b^3}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+b^3a)}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$(a+b+c)^4\geq(a+b+c)(a^3+b^3+c^3)+3(a^3c+b^3a+c^3b)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(3a^3b+6a^2b^2+12a^2bc)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Thus, $\frac{1}{3}$ is a minimal value.

Comment: Excuse me, i have some question about your old solution. In your first step using Holder, you added $a+b+kc$ but i didnt know how to find $k=3$. My apologize because i must have 50 reputation to comment to that question.

Comment: @DVdivi About which problem do you say. Can you give a link?

Comment: Oh i forgot https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430804/prove-this-inequality-sum-cyc-sqrt-fraca3b21-ge-frac32

Comment: @DVdivi I wrote $a+b+kc$ and I found $k$, for which the inequality would be true.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly ? I dont know where to start.